# Three.js javascript performance function construction

Tags: javascript, three.js

Inside `Object3D` you can see:

```
rotateX: function () {
    var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
    return function ( angle ) {
        return this.rotateOnAxis( v1, angle );
    };
}(),
```

Why not:

```
rotateX: function (angle) {
   var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
   this.rotateOnAxis( v1, angle );
},
```

(or something similar, that is, a pure 'direct' function.)

I know this is a pure JavaScript question but I'm curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other answer is somewhat misleading.

The fact that `v1` does not change is irrelevant.

The only reason the function is written this way is to prevent the `Vector3` object from being instantiated (and later garbage-collected) every time the function is called.

As written, `v1` is instantiated only once, and can be reused.

Here is another example from the `Object3D` class that uses the same pattern. Notice that the variable `q1` inside the closure is, in fact, changed in this case.

```
rotateOnAxis: function () {

    // rotate object on axis in object space
    // axis is assumed to be normalized

    var q1 = new THREE.Quaternion();

    return function ( axis, angle ) {

        q1.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle );

        this.quaternion.multiply( q1 );

        return this;

    }

}(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of `v1` doesn't change (it's the unit vector along the x-axis) there's no point to allocate it and then garbage collect it every time the function is called.

Instead, it's captured inside a function to ensure that it's not possible to modify it. This pattern is sometimes called an *immediate function*.

Note that the outer function is executed when `rotateX` is defined, and its value is assigned as the inner function. This inner function closes over the unchangeable value of `v1`.

Comment: Notice that `const` only means the variable doesn't change, not that the object it contains is not mutated (frozen).

Comment: @Bergi you're right. I removed the bit about const as I don't think it helped the discussion anyway. In a language like C++ you could make better guarantees about constness. In JS it's just a const reference, not a reference to a const :)